# How can logs generated by my java applications be aggregated in Azure?

Tags: java, azure, logging, azure-cloud-services, azure-application-insights

I am running a Java application on Azure Cloud Services.
I have seen this article which shows how to configure a java project to send logs to Azure insights using log4j: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-java-trace-logs/
However, for various reasons I do not want to do this. My java application already writes multiple log files in a log directory (application.log, error.log, etc). I want to point to this directory in Azure Insights so that it can aggregate these log files over multiple instances of my application running on Cloud Services and then present them to me. (In a similar way that AWS Cloudwatch presents logs). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a deep question and would require a bit of custom coding to accomplish it.

The problem as I read it is, you have multiple log files writing to a location and you just want to parse those log files and send the log lines. Moreover, you don't want to add the log appenders to your Java code for various reasons.

The short answer is, no. There isn't a way to have AI monitor a directory of log files and then send them.

The next short answer is, no. AI can't do it out of the box, but [Log Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/log-analytics/) can. This is a bit more heavy handed and I haven't read enough about it to say it would fit in this scenario. However, since you're using a cloud service you could more than likely install the agent and start collecting logs.

The next answer is the long answer, kinda. You can do this but it would require a lot of custom coding on your part. What I envision is something akin to how the Azure Diagnostics Sink works.

You would need to create an application that reads the log files and enumerates them line by line, it would then parse them based on some format and then call the [`TrackTrace()`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#track-trace) method to log it.

This option requires some considerable thought since you would be reading the file  and then determining what to do with it.